# Is the transitivity of subset proof incomplete everywere?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, proof-explanation, first-order-logic, formal-proofs

We are working in ZFC, so under first order logic we introduce the undefined predicate $\in$ and the ZFC axioms.

(1) $\forall A,B,C ((\forall(x \in A \rightarrow x \in B) \land \forall(x \in B \rightarrow x \in C)) \rightarrow \forall(x \in A \rightarrow x \in C))$

By universal elimination rule let $A', B',C'$ be sets.

(2) $(\forall(x \in A' \rightarrow x \in B') \land \forall(x \in B' \rightarrow x \in C')) \rightarrow \forall(x \in A' \rightarrow x \in C')$

Now by the deduction first order theorem if we can deduce $\forall(x \in A' \rightarrow x \in C')$ from $(\forall(x \in A' \rightarrow x \in B') \land \forall(x \in B' \rightarrow x \in C'))$, (2) and consequentially  the theorem (1) would be proved. So, we assume

(3) $(\forall(x \in A' \rightarrow x \in B') \land \forall(x \in B' \rightarrow x \in C'))$

To prove

(4) $\forall(x \in A' \rightarrow x \in C'))$

By universal elimination let $x'$ be a set.

(5) $x' \in A' \rightarrow x' \in C'$

**Z** (The Bourbaki danger)

By the deduction first order theorem again if we can deduce $x \in C'$  from $x \in A'$, then (5) would be proved. So, we assume

(6) $x' \in A'$

If we prove $x' \in C'$ then we have proved (5) and so (4),(2) and (1).

By (6) and (3)

(7) $x' \in B'$

By (7) and (3)

$x' \in C'$ QED!

In all the places where I found the theorem (1) ('the transitivity of subset'), there is some version of this proof that is considered complete and correct. However, it seem to me that this proof is not correct if first we not analyze the case $A'$ is empty in which case (2) is true by vacuity, then we can assume $A'$ is not empty. If we don't do that, (6) is a contradiction in the case $A'$ is empty and so the whole proof is wrong. Am I the wrong one? If so, why?

Comment: What is "Z (The Bourbaki danger)" ???

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA The little swish often used in Bourbaki to indicate an important detail, I assume.

Comment: This doesn't even look like a proof of the first formula -- instead it starts by deriving things _from_ it (by universal elimination, etc), thus begging the question. It is possible that it's a garbled description of how to _find_ a proof, but it's not the proof itself.

Comment: Right Daniel, that is the idea. Mauro your proof is good but using Hypothetical Syllogism you hide that for a 'moment' you assume that x' is in A' and that cannot be if A' is empty I have used the 'Z' to highlight the point I have doubt.

Comment: To HenningMakholm and DanielSchepler, your both last comments have been useful for me, they have put me on the right direction (I hope) on how to handle auxiliary hypotheses that arise on proofs of an interactive theorem prover I am building. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's your basic mistake:

> If we don't do that, (6) is a contradiction in the case $A'$ is empty and so the whole proof is wrong. Am I the wrong one?

There's nothing wrong with having contradictory *assumptions* at some point in a proof. On the contrary, that is a *good* thing to happen, because it means you can use the Principle of Explosion to conclude *whatever you want* right away and be done with that branch of the proof.

A more semantic way of saying this is that, finding yourself with contradictory assumptions means that you're in a branch of the proof that doesn't correspond to a possible situation you're trying to prove something about. Therefore *no proof is needed* in that branch -- or, in yet other words, "eh, whatever" will suffice as a proof. That's the reasoning behind the principle of explosion.

If your particular case, you don't even *have* a contradicting assumption, only the *possibility* that there is no $x\in A'$ to prove anything about. Again, this is not a problem for a proof: if it turns out that $A'$ is empty, it still doens't harm you to have had a plan for what to do with its elements.

Comment: Thank god someone understand my question. However, as far a know the only place where contradiction are welcome is in reductio ad absurdum. On the “Principle of Explosion” entry of Wikipedia state “Due to the principle of explosion, the existence of a contradiction (inconsistency) in a formal axiomatic system is disastrous”. By first order logic (6) x’ ∈ A’  but if A’ is empty then ¬(x’ ∈ A’) that is a disastrous contradiction. Would you please make your explanation more accessible? I would appreciate that.

Comment: @CarlosFreites: If you can derive a contradiction from your axioms _without_ making any local assumptions for, _then_ a disaster happens. But if a contradiction arises _while_ a local-to-this-proof assumption is in effect, it just means you're in a part of the proof you don't need to do more work on. The results of the explosion will be contained because you need some final proof step to discharge the assumption _after_ the explosion happens.

Comment: @CarlosFreites A typical example of where you'd use principle of explosion would be in proving $P\vee Q, \lnot P \vdash Q$.  Here, you would apply the $\vee$ elimination rule and then you need to prove two cases: $P \vee Q, \lnot P, P \vdash Q$ and $P \vee Q, \lnot P, Q \vdash Q$.  The second is easy; for the first case, since you have both $\lnot P$ and $P$ you can conclude $\bot$ and then use the explosion principle to get the desired conclusion $Q$.  (So as Henning said, one interpretation is that you're actually showing the first case can't ever happen.)

Answer (score 0):

One point of view which might be useful would be the [Curry-Howard correspondence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curry%E2%80%93Howard_correspondence): this point of view interprets (formal) proofs as being programs in a certain typed lambda calculus.  (And the more typical informal proofs written in mathematical papers and textbooks correspond to pseudocode...)

So, for this problem, the "program" you need to build is one which takes inputs of a proof of $A \subseteq B$ and a proof of $B \subseteq C$, and outputs a proof of $A \subseteq C$.  Furthermore, a "proof" of $A \subseteq B$ consists of a function which takes an object $x : V$ and a proof of $x \in A$ and outputs a proof of $x \in B$ -- and similarly for $B \subseteq C$ and $A \subseteq C$.  So, what the typical proof that you outlined does to construct this program is: given inputs $x : V$ and $HA : x \in A$, it first feeds $x$ and $HA$ into the input proving $A \subseteq B$ to get a proof of $HB : x \in B$; then, it feeds $x$ and $HB$ into the input proving $B \subseteq C$ to get $HC : x \in C$.  In summary, the proof ends up transforming to the "program"
$$ \lambda (A, B, C : V) (HAB : A \subseteq B) (HBC : B \subseteq C) . (\lambda (x : V) (HA : x \in A) . HBC(x, HAB(x, HA))). $$

Now, where I have been leading up to in this discussion is: the "programming language" for first-order logic allows for some types to be empty.  On the other hand, you don't necessarily have to make special allowances for the possibility that one of the types might be empty in writing programs: as long as the proof "type-checks" then the corresponding program will automatically handle these cases correctly.  So for example, if $A$ is an empty set, then for any $x : V$ then the type $x \in A$, consisting of all proofs that $x \in A$, will be an empty type; therefore, in this case it will not ever be possible for this function to be called since there is no possible input for the $HA$ parameter.

(On the other hand, the explosion principle mentioned in other answers corresponds to a family of operators $except_A : \bot \to A$, where $\bot$ is a canonical empty type and $A$ is an arbitrary type.  What this means is: if at some point your program seems to be able to construct an element of the empty type $\bot$, then that means that branch of the code must be unreachable, so whatever type you're supposed to be returning from that part of the code, you can just return a synthetic value of that type in order to satisfy the type checker.)